# Ipython notebook does not print all output in a code

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have two problem in ipython juypter

1) I want ipython to print all the output without without typing print. Ipython usually prints only the last result

2) I am using python interface of  [Madagascar package](http://www.ahay.org/wiki/Main_Page) , ( geophysical software) but when I use it in ipython notebook I don't any output.

```
import m8r
import urllib

#Retrieve
m8r.Fetch('french','french.asc')
fren='french.asc'

french=m8r.dd(form='native').transp().scale(dscale=2)[fren]  
french.grey(color='j',allpos='y',bias=1000,scalebar='n',barlabel='Depth',barunit='m',screenratio=1,title='French model').image()

nx = 161
dx = 51.325
nz = 401
dz = 10.265
nxx= 10*(nx-1)+1
dxx= dx/10
dscal = 10/dx

refl=m8r.window(n1=1,f1=30).remap1(n1=nxx,o1=0,d1=dxx)[french]
rdip=m8r.deriv(none="0").scale(dscale=dscal)[refl]
slice =m8r.window(n1=1,f1=30).remap1(n1=nx,o1=0,d1=dx).unif2(n1=nz,d1=dz,v00='1,2')[french]
slice.grey(color='j',allpos='y',bias=1,title='2-D   slice',label1='Depth',unit1='m',screenratio=0.5,screenht=6).image()
```

this code works in sage notebook. when I run it in sage I get graphs but this does not happed in ipython notebook

Comment: For the graphs: it may be using matplotlib internally. Try running `%matplotlib inline` first to show plots in the notebook.

Comment: I did this but nothing happen. this code generates all the graphs needed in the ipython notebook directory but it does not show them

Comment: Then I expect you'll need to ask on a madagascar mailing list or forum whether it has any integration with Jupyter/IPython.